# Problem with TinyMce in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, tinymce

[image: TyniMce-magento]

When i disable tinyMce, i got

[image: tyniMce]

I don't know why...

Comment: Looks like browser cache? CTRL+R ? Do you have any JS errors in console?

Comment: thanks , but i was  disabled cache ...

Comment: and my console empty

Comment: I spoke about browser cache. Try to open in another browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem (most probably) is that you field is named `content`.
This means it will get the html id `content` in the dom.
But there is already an element with this id. It's the page container.
You can either change the name of your field or add a prefix to all ids of the form elements.
In the tab class that generates the form add this line:

```
 $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('post_');
```

anywhere in the code before calling `$this->setForm($form)` and after calling `$form = ....`.
Use the cms page admin as example. The page also contains a field called `content`, but the problem does not reproduce there because it is handled as I explained. [See the core code as reference](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Content.php#L67)